# Test list with parametrized generics in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty sure there is some trivial answer I wan't able to keyword correctly.

Python3's `typing` module contains typed lists (analogous to C# generics type of things). Yet I didn't find a simple way to do this:

```py
from typing import List                                                                                                                                          
if isinstance([1,2,3], List[int]):
    print('yay!')
```

I know about mypy (i didn't dig into its code though) but I don't want to use it. My question is: what is the simplest and cleanest way to achieve what I want to achieve ?

Comment: I do not understand what you actually want to achieve. What does it mean `to keyword correctly`?

Comment: "Use the right keywords to search a relevant answer to my question"
My question being: I want, using typing.List do something like that:
`
if [1,2,3,4] is a list which every member is an int:
     #do stuff
`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
def is_list_of_int(x):
    return isinstance(x, list) and all((isinstance(item, int) for item in x))
```

Note that only if x is a `list` you'd iterate over its items and check if they're of type `int`.